# How to simulate C# thread starvation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to induce/cause thread starvation so as to observe the effects in C#.

Can anyone kindly suggest a (simple) application which can be created so as to induce thread starvation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set thread priority and thread affinity

Worker class

```
class PriorityTest
{
    volatile bool loopSwitch;
    public PriorityTest()
    {
        loopSwitch = true;
    }

    public bool LoopSwitch
    {
        set { loopSwitch = value; }
    }

    public void ThreadMethod()
    {
        long threadCount = 0;

        while (loopSwitch)
        {
            threadCount++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} with {1,11} priority " +
            "has a count = {2,13}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority.ToString(),
            threadCount.ToString("N0"));
    }
}
```

And test

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PriorityTest priorityTest = new PriorityTest();
        ThreadStart startDelegate =
            new ThreadStart(priorityTest.ThreadMethod);

        Thread threadOne = new Thread(startDelegate);
        threadOne.Name = "ThreadOne";
        Thread threadTwo = new Thread(startDelegate);
        threadTwo.Name = "ThreadTwo";

        threadTwo.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        threadOne.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        threadOne.Start();
        threadTwo.Start();

        // Allow counting for 10 seconds.
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        priorityTest.LoopSwitch = false;

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Code mostly taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpriority.aspx) also if you have multicore system you may need to set [thread affinity](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a55733db-cac0-4ccb-a3cc-a584742b41f9/). You may also need to create more threads to see real starvation.

Comment: Good example. You might want to declare loopSwitch as volatile to prevent optimization problems.

Comment: You did not include any affinity in your code. On a multi-core system, this example shows that both threads run for 10 seconds (which is not intended), unless you add the line at the start: `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)1;` (which specifies that threads can only be scheduled on the first processor).

Answer (score 3):

Set the thread affinity for your application in the task manager so that it only runs on one core. Then start a busy thread in your application with a high priority.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this through just pure coding? (i.e. without the task manager part)

Comment: @Sean See process properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76yt3c0w.aspx